# Why my IF don’t return component <Item_burger />?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have burger’s menu) have different items, as result I want from different title to open different components)

```
const MenuItems = props => {
    const { title, price, composition } = props;
    let myComponent = require(`../` + `img/` + `${title}` + `.png`);
    const onClick=()=>{
        if(title!=='burger'){
            return (<Item_burger />)
            console.log(title)
        }

    }
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <img className="card-img-top mb-5" src={myComponent} alt="...."/>
                <div className="card shadow-sm">
                    <div className="card-body text-center">
                        <h3>
                            <strong>{title}</strong>
                        </h3>
                        <p className="card-text">
                            <strong>{composition}</strong>
                        </p>
                        <h4>{price}</h4>
                        <Link to={`burger/constructor/${title}`}> 
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-light" onClick={onClick}>Go to Lab of taste =></button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: A return in the event handler has nowhere to return to. What is the expected behavior you are looking for? A button with onClick inside `<Link>` doesn't make sense either

Comment: You'll want to learn about conditional rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: You probably want `<Item_burger />` to be rendered in the Route associated with the Link path. Suggest you study some router tutorials and examples in documentaion

Comment: Post your Routes also.

Comment: Your `onClick` is of no use, because you have wrap your `button` with `Link`. Once clicked it will not wait to execute your `onClick` function and directly redirects to  `burger/constructor/${title}` path. You should have Route to handle this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure your onClick does return `<Item_burger />` component, but this return value is not being used. You should use `react-router` to display `Item_burger` component under route of `burger/constructor/${title}`. Refer to https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic.

By the way, do not mix interpolation and concatenation, the following:

```
let myComponent = require(`../` + `img/` + `${title}` + `.png`);
```

can be written as:

```
let myComponent = require(`../img/${title}.png`);
```

Also, you should not use a `<button>` inside a `<Link>` - `Link` is an `a`. You can style `Link` to look like a button though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody) I don’t understand, why start works) I’ll do the same stuff) Maybe? it’s because I have a little practise) But I’m trying...